# Manual sorting sequence problem on delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-update

I have this SQL

```
;WITH Sorted AS (
    SELECT  authorid,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sorted) AS RowNumber
    FROM    author
    WHERE   authorid <> @id
)

UPDATE  p
SET     p.sorted = 
        (CASE 
            WHEN p.authorid =  @id THEN @id
            WHEN s.RowNumber >= @id THEN s.RowNumber + 1
            ELSE s.RowNumber
        END)
FROM    author p
        LEFT JOIN Sorted s ON p.authorid = s.authorid
```

But this code is problematic because I adds 1 the value, it works if the sequence is in order like 1,2,3,4,5.

But if delete a record, it messes-up everything

So overcome this issue, I was thinking if I can use the `primarykey` column to be the same value in the sorted column and even if I delete, the sort should work without any issues and the above code will sort the records properly.

Because at one point, only 1 item will be sorted either moving up or down.

Its more like the rows will be swapped,

Any idea how can I get this working?

Here is the [sample data](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=4454ec83-320f-419f-829b-6addfef1be37/c818a950-4b13-4102-872c-4661458bb42f/bea4648d-29a8-4069-9b8f-4251b4257d5e.cfm)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  And explain what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=4454ec83-320f-419f-829b-6addfef1be37/c818a950-4b13-4102-872c-4661458bb42f/bea4648d-29a8-4069-9b8f-4251b4257d5e.cfm

Comment: CFFiddle is broken. Also please ensure the question is stand alone without depending on external links. And ensure sample data is added as tabular text, not images or external links.

Comment: what you mean by broken

Comment: Why are you trying to maintain sorting order in the table? Just sort the data in the order you like when you `SELECT` the data.

Comment: this is the existing structure code is being build so i had to keep it same as consistency

Comment: Results: CFFiddle currently doesn't support some of the tags used in the cfm file like cfquery, cfqueryparam, cflocation. Check our help link.

Comment: What would really help is sample data and desired output. The cold fusion fiddle is not the answer. See here. [mcve]

Comment: Expected Ouput ? what paramter you will pass then output should be what ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comprehend why you would want to main a separate **continuous** number sequence in the table. Maintenance of this sequence will likely be much slower than calculating sort sequence on the fly each time you select from `author` table.

In any case, assuming you have a good reason, here is the code:

```
;WITH Sorted AS (
    SELECT  authorid,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY authorid ) AS RowNumber
    FROM    author
    -- If you want to exclude a specific author from sorting
    -- This will also not update sorted value for this author
    -- WHERE authorid <> @id
)
UPDATE a
SET sorted = RowNumber
FROM Sorted AS a
```

Comments:

If you are doing it for pagination, then [here is a typical method](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) of doing it.

RE: "Because at one point, only 1 item will be sorted either moving up or down." - a database table is not a linked list, where you move (re-link) items in the order you like. The ordering of Database table data on disk is determined by free space availability and data size (similar to how file space is allocated in an OS), and it will not be in the order of `sorted` column unless it has a clustered index. If you have a clustered index, then SQL server will "try to maintain" the order, but again it will not be re-ordering already existing data on disk, unless you explicitly tell it to (`ALTER INDEX ... ON ... REBUILD`).

Comment: Thanks @alex, but the issue is when i delete whole sorting gets messed up, that is what i am trying to solve

Comment: I don't see how it would get messed up, if you run the `UPDATE` statement immediately after. Can you clarify exectly what gets messed up, is it values in sorted column or the order of records returned? Note: In my query you can change `OVER ( ORDER BY authorid )` to `OVER ( ORDER BY sorted )` or whatever the sorting column is.

Comment: so where will the passed id of the record will go, in my original code, i am using the idd which is fetching that record and updating, it, you provided a query without any id being passed and how this will manipulate the data, i am still confused, i tried running your query by passing authorid which makes sense but how will i make this work in my code, i am still lost in dark

Comment: You don't need to pass an author ID, **IF you delete the record before hand**, as you say you do. Either I misunderstand you, or you should read up a little on how databases work.